# jquery image zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am using a script to enlarge an image on hover, however it enlarges from the top-left and i need it to hover from the centre and i cannot figure out how to add the css into the jquery to add negative margin so it goes the way i want it to, here is the script.

```
$('#sun').width();
$('#sun').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
    $(this).animate({width: "7%"}, 'slow');
});
$('#sun').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({width: "6%"}, 'slow');
});
```

i just want "margin w x y z" in the css but cant get it :/ any one able to help? Thank you :)

Comment: do you want to animate negative margin or just add it?

Comment: animate that way it'll appear like it's enlarging from the centre of the image not the top-left corner. thanks.

Comment: You can do this with just CSS3. Set container to half size, image to 100% width and on hover add a scale transform and a transition. http://jsbin.com/uqovof/1/edit

Comment: yeh i know but it sorta has to be jquery....or flash builder but i'd rather not use the POS -'- hate flash builder haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are absolutely positioned, you could do this http://jsfiddle.net/8wGtp/.

```
$('#resize').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '130px', height: '130px', top: '-=15px', left: '-=15px'}, 500);
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).animate({width: '100px', height: '100px', top: '+=15px', left: '+=15px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed, yeh they are absolutely positioned, thanks again! :)